# How do I change the label of a raw device?

Tags: linux

I would like to change the name of `sda` to Arch. How do I do that?
I used `e2label` but it only works on filesystems and not on the raw disk.

```
nishant@arch ~ % lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,uuid
NAME   MOUNTPOINT LABEL                SIZE UUID
sda               Lubuntu 14.10 i386 298.1G 2014-10-22-18-35-29-00
├─sda1 /boot      ArchBoot              99M 185f7c65-f7d0-48b0-88c2-ad47b843111f
└─sda2 /          ArchHome             298G 66404f2f-d171-4558-a842-485d2a28214d
sr0                                   1024M
```

Comment: Hmm that's kind of weird. It seems some leftover of a Lubuntu iso (that is previously on the drive) remains. What `fstype` does sda has if you add `fstype` to `-o`? I bet it's `iso9660`? You probably want to run `wipefs` skilfully on sda to wipe the iso9660 signature while keeping your partition table intact. Dry run it with `-a -n` and see what's the proper `-t` you need (`-t iso9660`?).

Comment: Its `iso9660`? I don't want to mess up. Do you mean `wipefs -a -n /dev/sda` first? It says the resource is busy.

Comment: Yeah to see what signature it TRIES (`-n`) to erase, and then add an appropriate `-t` as mentioned as a filter and run again. If the verbose output shows that it runs as how you desired, then remove the `-n` to make it actually work.

Comment: You probably need to do it with some live cd/usb, since it's your system drive.

Comment: Alright Thanks. I will do this when I down my system! Its mostly up all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the switch to systemd it is actually not possible to change the default kernel device names anymore afaik. All that we can do is to create custom device symlinks with a udev rule. To do that, create a file in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` named something like `80-custom.rules`. The precise name doesn't matter as long as it matches the convention. In that file add the line:

```
KERNEL=="sda", SYMLINK+="arch"
```

Then after the next reboot, the system will create a symlink `/dev/arch` which points to `/dev/sda`.

Comment: This seems to be a very good answer; wonder if it still works in (e.g.) Debian 'bookworm'?